# Convert a tree to a matrix Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, tree

I'm trying to convert a Tree: (list Nat (listof Tree)) to a graph matrix but I do not know where to start. I'm not looking for code but more so ideas on how to approach this problem.

For example, a tree is

```
aTree = [3 , [
             [1 , []] ,
             [0 , [
                  [2 , []] ,
                  [5 , []]
                  ]
             ] ,
             [4 , []]
            ]
         ]
```

Which would look like:

```
       3
    /  |  \
   1   0   4
      / \
     2   5
```

And the matrix would be

```
aM =

    [[0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1] ,
     [0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0] ,
     [1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0] ,
     [1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0] ,
     [0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0] ,
     [1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]]
```

the function would be `treetomatrix(Tree, N)` where `N` is the number of vertices in the tree. So `treetomatrix(aTree, 6) => aM`.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really hard part of this question is how to change the weird list structure you're using into a dictionary.  (If you don't know about dictionaries, read up on them.  They do what you're trying to make your list do, but much more naturally.) I've skipped that for the moment, and will do that next.

```
aTree = {3 : {
               1: {},
               0:{  2: {}, 
                    5: {}
                 }
               4:{}
             }
        }

def tree_to_matrix(tree, n):
    return tree_to_mat(tree, [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])

def tree_to_mat(tree, mat):
    for k, v in tree.items():
        for i in v.keys():
            mat[i][k] = mat[k][i] = 1
        mat = tree_to_mat(v, mat)
    return mat

print(tree_to_matrix(aTree, 6))
```

prints

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Which is our desired output.  You may find it easier to read your input into a custom Tree class and then write a method for that class to generate the matrices.  The trick is to use recursion and realize that you have to set both `mat[i][k]` and `mat[k][i]` at the same time.

EDIT: Here's my hacky way of turning your list into a dict.

```
def dictify(l):
    return {l[0]: d_helper(l[1])}

def d_helper(l):
    d={}
    for i in l:
        d.update(dictify(i))
    return d 

dictify(aTree)
```

There's a better way, but this works.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I haven't gone through the first part of the answer yet because I am trying to understand dictify. What is d1 and d2 referring to?

Comment: @user7526205 Oops, those were the dummy names I gave those two functions when I was writing them.  Will fix